# What's the most efficient way to retrieve django queryset with the hightest number of posts for a related name?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter

I'm currently working on a website where advertisements will be posted to display vehicles for sale and rent. I would like to retrieve a queryset that highlights only one car brand (*i.e. Audi*) which has the highest number of posts for the respective `model`. Example:

[image]

Displaying the *Audi* brand because it has the highest number of related posts.

**My question is, what's the most efficient way of doing this?** I've done some work here but I'm pretty sure this is not the most efficient way. What I have is the following:

```
# Algorithm that is currently retrieving the name of the brand and the number of related posts it has.
def top_brand_ads():
     queryset = Advertisement.objects.filter(status__iexact="Published", owner__payment_made="True").order_by('-publish', 'name')

     result = {}
     for ad in queryset:
          # Try to update an existing key-value pair
          try:
               count = result[ad.brand.name.title()]
               result[ad.brand.name.title()] = count + 1

          except KeyError:
               # If the key doesn't exist then create it
               result[ad.brand.name.title()] = 1


     # Getting the brand with the highest number of posts from the result dictionary
     top_brand = max(result, key=lambda x: result[x])  # Returns for i.e. (Mercedes Benz)

     context = {
          top_brand: result[top_brand]  # Retrieving the value for the top_brand from the result dict.
     }
     
     print(context)  # {'Mercedes Benz': 7} -> Mercedes Benz has seven (7) related posts.
     return context
```

Is there a way I could return a queryset instead without doing what I did here or could this be way more efficient?

If the related models are needed, please see below:

**models.py**

```
# Brand
class Brand(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to='brand_logos/', null=True, blank=True)
     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
     ...
     # Methods


# Owner
class Owner(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     telephone = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
     alternate_telephone = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
     user_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
     payment_made = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     expiring = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
     ...
     # Methods


# Advertisement (Post)
class Advertisement(models.Model):
     STATUS_CHOICES = (
         ('Draft', 'Draft'),
         ('Published', 'Published'),
     )

     owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
     brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
     publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
     status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='Draft')
     ...
     # Other fields & methods
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need brands, let's query on Brand model:

```py
Brand.objects.filter(advertisement__status__iexact="Published").\
              filter(advertisement__owner__payment_made=True).\
              annotate(published_ads=Count('advertisement__id')).\
              order_by('-published_ads')
```

However, even in your proposed solution, you can improve a little bit:

1. Remove the `order_by` method from your queryset. It doesn't affect the final result but adds some overhead, especially if your `Advertisement` model is not indexed on those fields.
2. Every time you call `ad.brand` you are hitting the database. This is called the N+1 problem. You are in a loop of n, you make n extra db access. You can use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to avoid such problems. In your case: `Advertisement.objects.select_related('brand')...`

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful explanation, it really helped a lot and has expanded my knowledge base some more. I've edited your answer with what worked for me though. Thanks again! +1 vote for you man! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the edits. If this is the thing that worked for you, you probably have set `related_query_name=advertisement` for your `brand` field of `Advertisement` model. If I'm right, I suggest you add it to the question source for the sake of future readers.

Comment: No, I haven't set `related_query_name` on the `brand` field of the `Advertisement` model. But I'll continue to investigate it to see if it will break at some point which I doubt it will. :-)

Comment: My bad. It defaults to model name (advertisement here). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the count method?

```
from django.db.models import Count

Car.objects.annotate(num_views=Count('car_posts_related_name')).order_by('num_views')
```

Comment: Already tried this approach. However, it doesn't give me the answer I want. The closest I really get is when I tried using `aggregate`; but still doesn't give me exactly what I want. This `Advertisement.objects.filter(...).order_by(...).aggregate(top_brand=Count('brand__name'))` give me a result of `{'top_brand': 8}`. Not what I want. What I want is specifics as outlined in my example. `{'Mercedes Benz': 7}`.